# Move google maps like twittervision

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I would really like to have my google map app. move nicely around the markers like in  [twittervision.com](http://twittervision.com)

This works OK when the distance is shorter but it just jumps off when the distance is greater

Can anyone advice?

Comment: Wow! I can't believe no knows about this

Answer (score 0):

Just was googling for the same. Came across this and although I have not tried it, I thought you might find it helpful: http://www.akchauhan.com/create-or-move-google-map-marker-like-twittervisioncom/